# Are there any regular Open Data conferences?

Tags: data-request, calendar, social-process

I'm interested in any Open Data conferences which are held on a regular basis (e.g., yearly). Are there any such conferences?

Comment: What do you qualify as an 'open data' conference?  I've helped with [Research Data Access & Preservation](http://www.asis.org/rdap/) the past few years, and although there's a ton of crossover, and it'd be of use to people dealing with open data, it's not *specifically* about it.

Comment: @Joe I'm talking about Open Data in its broadest sense, the RDAP conference seems related enough to me so I'd add it to the community wiki answer with a clear description of the conference's focus.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Conferences:

- [TransparencyCamp](http://transparencycamp.org/), by the Sunlight Foundation, annually since 2009.
- [Open Knowledge Conference (OKCon)](http://okcon.org/), annually since 2005. Open data has been central since its inception - in 2012 this expanded to be the [Open Knowledge Festival (OKFestival)](http://okfestival.org/).
- [Open Government Data Camp](http://opengovernmentdata.org/events/), by the Open Knowledge Foundation, annually since 2010. From 2012 the camp has been merged with the Open Knowledge Conference.
- [European Open Data Week](http://opendataweek.org/), annually since 2012.
- [European Public Sector Information Platform (ePSI) Conference](http://epsiplatform.eu/conference2013), annually since 2012.
- [European Data Forum](http://www.data-forum.eu/), focused on Linked Data, annually since 2012.
- [Health Datapalooza](http://healthdatapalooza.org/), focused on U.S. open health data, annually since 2010
- [National Day of Civic Hacking](http://hackforchange.org/), annually since ~2010
- [International Open Government Data Conference](http://www.data.gov/sites/default/files/conference/iodgc_program_guide_2012_web.pdf), started in 2010
- [Open Data Day](http://opendataday.org/) is an annual event since 2009
- [Open Data Exchange](http://odx13.com/) started in 2013, and will become an annual event.
- [The Computer-Assisted Reporting conference](https://www.ire.org/conferences/nicar-2013/) (often referred to as NICAR) is held annually by Investigative Reporters and Editors and focuses on obtaining and using open data in a journalism context.
- [IEEE Big Data](http://www.ischool.drexel.edu/bigdata/bigdata2013/callforpaper.htm), a journal on big data which includes calls on open data
- [OpenSym](http://www.opensym.org/), OpenSym includes a track specifically for open data
- [Open Data Science Conference](https://odsc.com/) began in 2015, held several times each year (i.e. 2-4) on both the east and west coasts of the U.S. as well as internationally (e.g. Kiev, Bangalore, Tokyo, etc.).  Emphasis on data science but also touches on open ideas, software, and data.

(people might want to expand this community wiki)

Comment: Might we want to sub-set specialized open data conferences (e.g. Health Datapalooza) to make the list more navigable?

Comment: @batpigandme : as the list gets larger, it might be worth splitting them out by continent or other geographic area, or by the specific type of data they focus on.

Comment: @Joe +1, I'm not all that familiar with how community wikis evolve on SE, but would it be easier to set up categories before hand or just let them grow organically?

Comment: See my answer about Lanyrd: It could make sense to contribute to the wiki there because they have a larger existing catalog of open data events and user base.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. In addition to the list provided above, the website [Lanyrd](http://lanyrd.com/), a collaboratively edited wiki about conferences around the globe, has over [250 events](http://lanyrd.com/topics/open-data/) (both past and upcoming) tagged as "open data."

It could make sense for this community to contribute to that wiki, rather than maintaining a separate wiki listing here, since they have a larger user base and existing listing of events.

Comment: Some minor problems with that suggestion: the first is that they track each conference instance, so it's more difficult to tell how often they reoccur (annually, etc).  They also track [less formal events](http://lanyrd.com/2013/friday-lunchtime-lectures-will-open-data-give-ci-2/) that I wouldn't qualify as a conference.  It might also miss related events that aren't specifically on "open data" but have a high overlap / synergy.  As a librarian, I think it's worth maintaining a curated list, possibly also linking to the lanyrd entries.

Comment: @Joe I hear your point - however, it's possible to create a "Guide" that is just populated by conferences that are major and recur--that may be one way to get around your concern.

Comment: they really don't make the 'guide' stuff obvious, but that'd probably work ... a little more playing around suggests that it's possible to collect up conferences into '[series](http://lanyrd.com/series/)', but they seem to be second class citizens (no tagging the series as a whole, the list is presented with no detail or order, can't get from a conference to the series, I can't even figure out how I got there, etc)  I haven't actually created an account, so I don't know if you can list 'series' in a guide, or only 'conferences'

Answer (score 5):

[csv,conf](http://csvconf.com/): "A conference for data makers everywhere. (And any data - not just CSVs!)"

- **3-4 May 2016 in Berlin, Germany.**
- 2014-07-24: Berlin (one day, first edition). "This one day conference will focus on practical, real-world stories,
  examples and techniques of how to scrape, wrangle, analyze, and visualize
  data. Whether your data is big or small, tabular or spatial, graphs or rows
  this event is for you."

---

Full public announcement of the 2014 edition:

> Announcing CSV,Conf - the conference for data makers everywhere
>   http://csvconf.com/ which takes place on 15 July 2014 in Berlin.
>
> This one day conference will focus on practical, real-world stories,
>   examples and techniques of how to scrape, wrangle, analyze, and
>   visualize data. Whether your data is big or small, tabular or spatial,
>   graphs or rows this event is for you. Key Info
>
> - Where: Kalkscheune, Berlin, Germany
> - When: 15 July 2014, all day
> - Web: http://csvconf.com/
> - Register: http://register.csvconf.com/
>
> CSV,Conf is run in conjunction with the week long Open Knowledge
>   Festival http://okfestival.org/. What Is It About? Building
>   Community
>
> We want to bring together data makers/doers/hackers from backgrounds
>   like science, journalism, open government and the wider software
>   industry to share tools and stories. For those who love data
>
> CSV Conf is a non-profit community conference run by some folks who
>   really love data and sharing knowledge. If you are as passionate about
>   data and the application it has to society then you should join us!
>   Big and small
>
> This isn’t a conference just about spreadsheets. We are curating
>   content about advancing the art of data collaboration, from putting
>   your CSV on GitHub to producing meaningful insight by running large
>   scale distributed processing. Colophon: Why CSV?
>
> This conference isn’t just about CSV http://data.okfn.org/doc/csv
>   data. But we chose to call it CSV Conf because we think CSV embodies
>   certain important qualities that set the tone for the event:
>
> - Simplicity: CSV is incredibly simple - perhaps the simplest structured    data format there is
> - Openness: the CSV ‘standard’ is well-known and open - free for anyone    to use
> - Easy to use: CSV is widely supported - practically every spreadsheet    program, relational database and programming language
>     in existence can    handle CSV in some form or other
> - Hackable: CSV is text-based and therefore amenable to manipulation and    access from a wide range of standard tools
>     (including revision control    systems such as git, mercurial and
>     subversion)
> - Big or small: CSV files can range from under a kilobyte to gigabytes    and its line-oriented structure mean it can be
>     incrementally processed –    you do not need to read an entire file to
>     extract a single row. Received on Thursday, 19 June 2014 09:36:02 UTC