# Journals for Open Data research

Tags: data-request, research

I found this [great question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/517/are-there-any-regular-open-data-conferences) about regular open data conferences.

But do you know if there are journals only or part of them for Open Data case studies and research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems research is interdisciplinary.

- For technical aspects I would look, for example, at journals that publish research on linked data.
- For business models etc management journals.
- For public sector information, journals that focus on pubic administration.

More research might be in Information Systems and others.

We at the ODI started a [Zotero group](https://www.zotero.org/groups/odi/items) for open data papers, but early stages.

Comment: Thank you @Ulrich. Please let me keep the question open for a few days to attract more answers. After that I will choose one for the "best answer".